# Transfer License keys of Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, installation, licence

I want to transfer my sharepoint 2013 license keys in the new server. Can anyone tell me the process of it?

Can Do like below ?:

- use the same key in the new installation
- After successfully setup done, I will demolish my old server.

Is this the right way to do it?

Please Suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is right way to do the thing. As long as you hold the License.

- Build the new farm using the same keys
- Once everything setup or migrated from existing farm then delete the old farm.

Comment: If i am doing in the same way, Do i need to pay anything extra for the new server?

Comment: When I am using the same product key , surprisingly it gives error like it is not valid for the product. But the same product key is working on my existing farm.

Comment: U don't need the new license for new server as long u decommissioning old. I am not sure why it is saying this. Make sure you typed the correct key